# build up css selectors path with multiple patterns

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, cypress

I have multiple selectors as following. is there any way for me to use multiple pattern to build up css path? something like `.css_selector--${IamClassOne | SomethingRandom | ThisisRandomAgain}-`?

```
<div class="css_selector--IamClassOne-variable1">
<div class="css_selector--SomethingRandom-variable2">
<div class="css_selector--ThisisRandomAgain-variable2">
```

Comment: XY problem — Not sure why you'd want to be doing this. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i am writing some frontend test by selenium that need to selector element by using selectors location to refer element.and i have one function need to select all above element with different class

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do string concatenation — making a string that you can use as a css selector.

```js
function generateSelector (part1, part2) {
    var cssSelector = '.css_selector--' + part1 + '-' + part2;
    return cssSelector;
}
// Usage:
var selector1 = generateSelector('IamClassOne', 'variable1');
var selector2 = generateSelector('SomethingRandom', 'variable2');
```

Comment: if there is anyway to use "OR", "and" logic in css?

Comment: @jacobcan118 what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with Cypress (**not Selenium**), you can create custom commands

It is not clear want you want back, is it ALL or FIRST ONE?

Can search on ***partial*** class selector by using these expressions,

- `[class^="ClassBeginsWithThis"]` where ^= means the class string starts with the selector
- `[class*="ClassContainsThis"]` where *= means the class string has selector somewhere inside.

---

**All**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getAll', {previousSubject: false}, (selectorArray) => {

  const foundElements = selectorArray
    .map(selector => Cypress.$(`[class^="css_selector--${selector}"]`)
    .filter(x => x);  // remove not-found

  if (foundElements.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No elements found");  // Fail the test, since none exist
  }

  return cy.wrap(foundElements);
});

// Usage
cy.getAll(['IamClassOne', 'SomethingRandom', 'ThisisRandomAgain']);
```

**First**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getFirst', {previousSubject: false}, (selectorArray) => {

  const foundElements = selectorArray
    .map(selector => Cypress.$(`[class*="css_selector--${selector}"]`)
    .filter(x => x);  // remove not-found

  if (foundElements.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No elements found");  // Fail the test, since none exist
  }

  return cy.wrap(foundElements[0]);
});

// Usage
cy.getFirst(['IamClassOne', 'SomethingRandom', 'ThisisRandomAgain']);
```